# Tools to check network censorship and other ISP limitations

Tags: networking, internet, dns, kali-linux-tools

I was looking for Linux tools to check my ISP performance & limitations but I didn't find any specific tools. I know that it may be illegal & the ISP can terminate my service but I want to know are there any espionage-like tools to check my ISP?
Like checking the bandwidth limitations on specific domains, bandwidth-throttling, DNS (Filtering, Redirection, Hijacking, Spoofing), etc.
Preferably on Ubuntu 22.04 but if there are other tools that can be used only on Kali distro, I appreciate it.
P.S: I know there are some tools like OONI but I want more professional details on what's going on my ISP and network.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user68186 22.04

Comment: Please add this information in your question.

Comment: Why not either dual boot Kali Linux or run Kali in a virtual machine? That way whatever you do with the Kali Linux tools installer katoolin script and the espionage-like tools won't blow back on Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel actually I want to know if there are any specific tools for mentioned purposes whether on Ubuntu or Kali distro, there are tools like nmap & Wireshark but I don't know if they are the best tools for *eavesdropping* the ISP!

Comment: Kali is off topic so that part will not be answered here.